# How to convert between shared_ptr<FILE> to FILE* in C++?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, wofstream, wifstream

I am trying to use a FILE pointer multiple times through out my application 
for this I though I create a function and pass the pointer through that. Basically I have this bit of code

```
     FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"ftest.txt", L"r");
    _setmode (_fileno(fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    wifstream file(fp);
```

which is repeated and now instead I want to have something like this:

```
wifstream file(SetFilePointer(L"ftest.txt",L"r"));
....
wofstream output(SetFilePointer(L"flist.txt",L"w"));
```

and for the function :

```
FILE* SetFilePointer(const wchar_t* filePath, const wchar_t * openMode)
{
    shared_ptr<FILE> fp = make_shared<FILE>();
    _wfopen_s (fp.get(), L"ftest.txt", L"r");
    _setmode (_fileno(fp.get()), _O_U8TEXT);
    return fp.get();
}
```

this doesn't simply work. I tried using `&*fp` instead of `fp.get()` but still no luck.

Comment: Maybe [this idea](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h) is of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks , but there you are converting a File* to a shared_ptr, i am using a shared_ptr and im stuck how to reverse it.! I am clueless :-/

Comment: Well, your approach simply makes no sense. When you say `make_shared<FILE>`, you're effectively saying `new FILE`, which is totally wrong, since `FILE` is an *opaque* type.

Comment: So what should i do then? i dont want to have repeated code , i cant think of any other way! i would be grateful if you can further guide me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supposed to create `FILE` instances with `new` and destroy them with `delete`, like `make_shared` does. Instead, `FILE`s are created with `fopen` (or in this case, `_wfopen_s`) and destroyed with `fclose`. These functions do the allocating and deallocating internally using some unspecified means.

Note that `_wfopen_s` does not take a pointer but a *pointer to pointer* - it changes the pointer you gave it to point to the new `FILE` object it allocates. You cannot get the address of the pointer contained in `shared_ptr` to form a pointer-to-pointer to it, and this is a very good thing - it would horribly break the ownership semantics of `shared_ptr` and lead to memory leaks or worse.

However, you *can* use `shared_ptr` to manage arbitrary "handle"-like types, as it can take a custom *deleter* object or function:

```
FILE* tmp;
shared_ptr<FILE> fp; 
if(_wfopen_s(&tmp, L"ftest.txt", L"r") == 0) {
  // Note that we use the shared_ptr constructor, not make_shared
  fp = shared_ptr<FILE>(tmp, std::fclose);
} else {
  // Remember to handle errors somehow!
}
```

Please do take a look at [the link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h) @KerrekSB gave, it covers this same idea with more detail.